# Change css for a new row added in TableView Javafx

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

I'm sorry for mistake I'm french.
So I have a tableView empty. I have a button "Add" when on click added row in a tableView. And when I select an row in my tableView, a new button "Cancel" show. 
And when I click on a button "Cancel", the row's css change on my row selected (added a class css ".cancel").

The problem is that I click on button "Cancel", and after I click in the button "Add", the css ".cancel" is applicated at an other row while I don't clicked in the button "Add".

I think that there is a problem in index row.

In my method initialize :

```
articleTable.setRowFactory(param -> new TableRow<LigneTicket>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(LigneTicket paramT, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(paramT, empty);
            if (!isEmpty() && paramT != null && paramT.getArticle().isArticleCanceled()) {
                getStyleClass().add("cancel");
            }
        }
    });
```

my code on button "Cancel" :

```
    public void cancelLigneTicket() {
    int indexSelected = articleTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                     articleTable.getItems().get(indexSelected).getArticle().setArticleAnnuler(true);

articleTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

List<LigneTicket> items = new ArrayList<>(articleTable.getItems());

articleTable.getItems().setAll(items);

buttonAnnulArt.setVisible(false);
```

Help !!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you ever remove the style class `cancel`? Also - you are probably better off using Pseudo Class, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072514/how-to-add-class-or-pseudoclass-programmatically-to-custom-control-in-javafx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883838/implement-read-only-style-in-javafx/36886291#36886291

Comment: No I don't remove the class "cancel" because every row selected and after clicked in the button "Cancel" must keep the class css "cancel". I have replace with the code "pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("cancel"), true);", but I don't work...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that you mean, but keep in mind that `TableView` re-uses rows, so if you have set a property on the row object, you have to make sure it is still valid with every `updateItem` - the same row may now be used for an item that wasn't cancelled!   

Also - what do you mean by they pseudo class not working? Same problem, or not changing style at all? Keep in mind pseudo classes have to be specified by : (colon) in the css, not . (period), so it should be ":cancel" rather than ".cancel" .

Comment: I changed in my css by ":cancel" and the css work, but the problem is always the same. If I click in button "Add" after the button "Cancel", the css is not applicated in the same row... The program applicate the css at an other row, and I don't click in the button "cancel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableRow`s are used to display the table items. That doesn't mean however, that it will be used with only one item.

This can result in the following sequence of events for a row `r`:

1. The item of `r` is updated to a canceled item and thus the `cancel` CSS class is added.
2. The item of `r` is updated to a non-canceled item, but the `cancel` CSS class is not removed.

You need to remove the class again. Furthermore with your code the style class could be added multiple times leading to unnecessary memory consumption.

```
boolean canceled = !empty && paramT != null && paramT.getArticle().isArticleCanceled());
if (canceled) {
     if (!getStyleClass().contains("cancel"))
          getStyleClass().add("cancel");
} else {
     getStyleClass().remove("cancel");
}
```

or using `PseudoClass`:

```
private static final PseudoClass CANCELED = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("cancel");

...
pseudoClassStateChanged(CANCELED, !empty && paramT != null && paramT.getArticle().isArticleCanceled());
```

Furthermore you should prefer the `TableView.refresh` (available in JavaFX >= 8u60) method to refresh the cell items instead of copying the list and setting the items.

Comment: It Works in adding "tableView.refresh". Thanks so mush